# Github markdown won't end a list

Tags: markdown

Writing a readme in github I run into the problem that if I want a paragraph of text after a list it interprets it as just more of the list:

```
* List item

More text
```

Shows up as:

- List item

  More text

I tried looking at a few other github repos but I can't tell why theirs are working and mine isn't.

[example](https://github.com/jnvsor/gw2rip/blob/5087c3e0060cc6ff0ea10a8895f998215b3a3cc9/README.md)

Comment: Have you tried to add more than just one new line between your last li and the new paragraph?

Comment: Yep - 5 or 6 in fact.

Comment: Can you please post also the content of your last li?

Comment: I can do you one better, [the readme](https://github.com/jnvsor/gw2rip/blob/master/README.md) is on github - just doesn't look right.

Comment: Apparently turning most of them into headers fixed the issue though I'd like to know why it's there in the first place. [new link](https://github.com/jnvsor/gw2rip/blob/5087c3e0060cc6ff0ea10a8895f998215b3a3cc9/README.md) shows the issue historically

Comment: The same problem. I learned that if you have even **one space** before the first letter of a text, coming after list (no matter how many empty lines) - it will turn it into a list item.

Answer (score 12):

You can also end a Markdown list using an HTML comment `<!-- -->`. The comment won't be visible in the rendered output and it works also on Stack Exchange sites.

It's just **important to place the comment on a separate line after the list and put an empty line *both* before and after it**.

The comment doesn't have to have any content:

```
- List item 1
- List item 2

<!-- end of the list -->

    code_block() {
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

In stack exchange posts and GitHub markdown you can use an HTML tag to force the end of a list:

```
- one
- two
- three

<a/>
    not a list item
```

produces:

- one
- two
- three

not a list item

Or on GitHub you can use a markdown comment:

```
- one
- two
- three

[//]: # (Hello)
    not a list item
```

A gist showing GitHub markdown: https://gist.github.com/schlueter/ee90c7097f633ac90d3a9da56e6a69e1

Comment: The <a/> ends a link, not a list. You may want to try </ul>. That is what worked for me.

Comment: `<a/>` is an empty link, not the end of one, which would be `</a>`. That trick doesn't require a specific tag, I just know `<a/>` works, and is working in my gist. `</ul>` also works in my gist. If only `</ul>` worked for you it may have to do with the markdown library you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You may add a new line after your list heading, and tab your list content. In this way when a new list is started it will be separate from previous list.

Answer (score 0):

For me `</p>` worked the best, after `</a>` i had trouble with following markdown syntax not being read.
So:

```
*   this
*   that </p>
**Next header**
```

will output

- this
- that

**Next header**

Oh and it seems like after `</p>` or `</a>` you can't write `<br>`..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two new lines to break out the context of the list.

```
* List item\n
\n
More text
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do that by writing two skipping line like this
`\n\n`

**for example**

```
1. this is a List Item 1
2. this is a List Item 2\n\n
Here I'm leaving the List.
```

**which will output the following:**

1. this is a List Item 1
2. this is a List Item 2\n\n

Here I'm leaving the List.