# Following a bulleted list by a code block in markdown

Tags: markdown

I frequently want to write an SO answer which consists of a bulleted list followed immediately by a block of code.  Usually, I muddle through this like this:

- One point
- Another point

Some verbiage

```
begin

end;
```

Quite often, the only reason I have to put something like the "Some verbiage" line is that if I don't, the code block doesn't appear as a normal code block, but as indented ordinary text.

I've tried the various answers to this q [Github markdown won't end a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313462/github-markdown-wont-end-a-list), but none of them seems to work correctly for me, at least none of them produces the visual appearance they claim (at least in the Answer editor preview), neither does what I usually use, i.e, four spaces before the lines of the code block or using <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>.  The only thing that *does* seem to work for me is using a "code fence", i.e. four back-quotes before and after the code block, but even that I find a pain.  Surely, there must be a simpler way of switching immediately from bulleted list format to a code block, but what is it?

Comment: On StackOverflow one has to indent 8 spaces i.o. 4. The first indentation meaning text under the bullet point, the extra indentation for code.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying 8 spaces before each code line (which imo is even worse than the code fence) or 8 before the first code line and 4 on each of the following?  * on the first and then 4 just seems to turn only the first line into a code block, the following 4 just indents, iyswim.

Comment: Every _code_ line 8 spaces on StackOverflow.